# How to get Authorization header value with swagger-generated java class

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I'm following the guide on https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/

I have `securityDefinitions` defined as

```
securityDefinitions:
  bearer_auth:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: Authorization
```

and the path is

```
/some-path:
  get:
    parameters:
      - description: cursor
        in: query
        name: cursor
        type: string
    produces:
      - application/json
    responses:
      ...
    tags:
      - ...
    security:
      - bearer_auth: []
```

The generated method looks like

```
@GET
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @ApiOperation(
        authorizations = {@Authorization("bearer_auth")},
        tags = {"..."}
    )
    @ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(
    code = 200,
    message = "...",
    response = Response.class
)})
Response foo(@QueryParam("cursor") @ApiParam("cursor") String cursor);
```

I need to validate the bearer token specified by `Authorization` header on backend, but the header value is not part of the parameters.
How do I get it?